# Laravel intermittent Bad Gateway 502 error and pages losing css styling

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, bad-gateway

Some pages when trying to load I receive a Bad Gateway Ngnix 502 error however upon page refresh it will resolve the page load. Not sure if this is associated however one page requires a heavy mssql query and the page will load with the result however will not continue to load CSS associated to the page.

master.blade.php file contains the bootstrap css and theme styling, extention.blade.php will extend the master (as with multiple other pages on my project) however it includes a DB query which successfully returns when dd() however fails to load the css. Other pages sometimes have this issue and multiple refresh will correct the page load.

Hope someone can help my situation. Sounds like a configuration issue? Just not sure..

**UPDATE**

All pages experience first a Bad Gateway 502 followed by a refresh of loss of CSS (bootstrap mainly). The Bad Gateway will come after 2 or 3 browser refresh on static pages with no association to DB queries.

My Setup:

- Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6
- PHP 7.1
- Nginx and Laravel 5.6

www.conf setup:

- pm = dynamic
- pm.max_children = 10
- pm.start_servers = 10
- pm.min_spare_servers = 10
- pm.max_spare_servers = 10

~/.valet/Nginx/Sites.dev-env (my projects directory where Valet is parked) has the following lines (added by myself to try and resolve this issue):

```
`fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/Users/myusername/.valet/valet.sock;
fastcgi_index 
/Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
/Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php;
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;`
```

php-fpm.conf setup:

- Default with     `include=/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.d/*.conf`

Laravel Storage has a 777 permission set (just to determine if its a file permission issue, this will be reverted back to 755 fyi)

Now the key to solving this issue is the error logs which provide the following:

php error log:

```
`[22-Feb-2018 10:29:06 Australia/Sydney] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught 
PDOException: SQLSTATE[25000]: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The ROLLBACK 
TRANSACTION request has no corresp$
Stack trace:
0 {main}
  thrown in [no active file] on line 0`
```

However, the only SQL I have related to this is a select query but I don't believe this is the main cause of the Bad Gateway.

~/.valet/log/nginx-error.log:

```
`2018/02/22 10:24:23 [error] 62179#0: *9 upstream prematurely closed 
connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 
127.0.0.1, server: sites.dev-env`
```

This I believe is the main issue. It occurs at every point of a Bad Gateway error and I am stuck trying to work out what exactly it means. This log file has a ton of these errors obviously me trying to work out what the. is going on.

How I resolve the issue temporarily is by doing a valet restart. A Brew restart of nginx or php doesn't resolve the issue, therefore, isolating this to valet.

Comment: do you see anything in ngnix logs?

Comment: Nothing found in the ngnix log.

Comment: have you checked the removing query is it working?

Comment: Also found when just viewing the souce code of the page, opened up the css shows fine and the jquery script produced a bad gateway, then reopening it will be fine. It's very intermittent and not related to querying the DB after all.

Comment: Found the only error is in the php log:

[20-Feb-2018 16:31:53 Australia/Sydney] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare valet_default_site_path() (previously declared in /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php:43) in /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line 43

Comment: may be you need to re-install valet

Comment: Yep I have done that and still the same error.. damn..

Comment: I have stopped valet, used php artisan serve to watch the files being loaded, artisan will stop completely after the first page (after login)

Comment: php artisan optimize
        php artisan clear-compiled
        php artisan cache:clear
        php artisan route:clear
        php artisan view:clear
        php artisan config:clear  Run tthese commands may it works

Comment: Also tried php artisan serve --port=8080 which worked for a single page, going to the next page stopped.

Comment: when using php artisan serve, php log shows:

`[20-Feb-2018 16:49:17 Australia/Sydney] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[25000]: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. in [no active file]:0
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in [no active file] on line 0`

Comment: I’ll give that a try tonight @adnan, mich appreciated for your time and support on this issue.

Comment: all pages loaded with success then the bad gateway occurred followed by missing CSS and now cannot get the CSS back to the page (with just a page refresh). Looking at the console the bootstrap theme css is giving a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()" error.

I will look into solving the bad gateway error first and hopefully it may have something to do with loading a page resource or at least narrow down the issue.

Comment: make sure these files have correct permissions

Comment: I have checked the file permissions and are properly set. Again looking into it further I did a brew upgrade on nginx which updated nginx to still get the error however further searching on Google I then located php-fpm.log to find the following error and finding multiple child processes are failing

Comment: `[21-Feb-2018 10:47:19] WARNING: [pool www] child 44641 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 415.973817 seconds from start
[21-Feb-2018 10:47:19] NOTICE: [pool www] child 45374 started`

Comment: I believe it could be relating to files associated to php writing sessions from what I have read but I am not sure where the sessions are writing to considering the session handling within Laravel is within the project itself and that I have ensured the files are open for read/write.

Comment: I have now narrowed down the issue. I was looking at the wrong error log. looking at the nginx error log located within the .valet directory I found:

Comment: `2018/02/21 11:48:43 [error] 55477#0: *3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: sites.dev-env, request: "GET /search HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/myusername/.valet/valet.sock:", host: "salesops.dev-env"`

Comment: you cannot have a dash in the host name, can you?

Answer (score 0):

I know only one reason why the page may not load on the first place, but load on the other. It is about `Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());`

On the first load there might be some inputs, on the refresh - no input would be left.

Comment: No this is incorrect. This error occurs on every page from static to DB driven query pages. This is not isolated to a specific page and pages with no input at all.

Comment: Well, anyway it is something to do with session, most likely login-engine, I believe. Can you Log::debug(... the contains of the sessions when there is a problem and when the problems is gone to see the difference?

Comment: Thank you Yevgeniy as that helps. I have Spatie User permissions package installed and just added now barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to view the routes, queries and session. It looks like Spatie's user permission is making 3 queries to gather user, roles and permissions when the query should be consolidated into one but I didn't find anything outside of this. Do you have any recommendation on debugging sessions within Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Just commenting here as I've come across another scenario that can cause this. Note that Yevgeniy's answer is also correct in causing a 502 if there is no referer header information.

Under load I was able to identify that that database was being hit particularly hard by some poorly performing queries. These queries appeared to be holding our database up and in doing so was causing the web server to go up and down several times a minute. It appeared as though PHP-FPM was constantly opening/closing database connections - maybe as a result of the open connections stalling due to the load.

Anyway - as a general answer to this, database struggles might result in your web tier locking up and getting returning a 502 error. Laravel doesn't give you must helpful information in this instance, but checking your database is something you may want to do if you start receiving intermittent errors like this.